# Closing parent popup window from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On domain1.com I have a link that opens a popup to domain2.com.  Within the popup is an iframe, also hosted on domain2.com.  From within the iframe, i am trying to close the popup window.  I seem to be getting confused on how to do this.  From the iframe, do I call a javascript function defined in the popup that will close the window?  Can I close the window directly from the iframe?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286426/javascript-closing-window-from-iframe). I think it'll apply.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using this: `parent.window.close();` or this: `top.window.close();`  you should be able to close it.

Comment: thank you, for some reason i was thinking cross domain restrictions would apply.